# JavaScript array map function how to determine the length and the index of current item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a js snippet which generate a table row with

**td** s as follows

```
                    var cols = this.props.cols;
                    data = this.state.data

                    return data.map(function (item) {
                        var cells = cols.map(function (colData) {
                            console.log(colData);
                            return <td>{item[colData.key]}</td>;
                        });


                        return <tr key={item.Id }>{cells}</tr>;
                    });
```

I want to determine the last column  and want to add a button that particular td
How to get the length of cells inside the cols.map(function(coldata). um not sure whether ill be able to accomplish it by this approach

Comment: want to get  the cells.length inside cols.map(function(coldata)

Comment: Then `cols.length` should help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map injects two more arguments you're not currently using. The full callback signature is (element, index, wholeArray). You can then call .length on the array and compare it to the current element index.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the other guy's answer, which is the same as mine and even says so.  :p

Answer (score 4):

something like this would work. As yaycmyk mentioned your map function can take 3 args..

```
 1. the iterated item
 2. the index of the item
 3. the array that is being iterated on.
```

I just just compare the index to the length - 1

```
                return data.map(function (item) {
                    var cells = cols.map(function (colData, idx, arr) {
                         return (idx === arr.length -1)
                               ? <td><button /></td>
                               : <td>{item[colData.key]}</td>;
                    });


                    return <tr key={item.Id }>{cells}</tr>;
                });
```